# Continuous indicator-like functions

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, continuity

Let $\Omega$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $g:x\in\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function such that

$$
\begin{cases}
g(x)>0 & x\in\text{int}\Omega,\\
g(x)=0 & x\in\partial\Omega,\\
g(x)<0 & x\notin\Omega.
\end{cases}
$$

So $g$ is somehow similar to an indicator function, but it is continuous, and can be used to tell when one is crossing the boundary of the set, because there it changes its sign. I like to call $g$ a pseudo-indicator function of $\Omega$.

**Questions**

1) Did I just come up with this concept, or if not, where can I read more about it? Most importantly: what would be the proper name for functions like $g$, if they have been studied in the literature?

2) Even if I am considering $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ for simplicity, intuition suggests that this concept may be defined for more general spaces. I just need the notions of differentiability and continuity to define $g$. What would be the most general setting, or at least, a more general setting? (For example: metric spaces, topological spaces, etc.)

Comment: Seems possibly related to distance functions sometimes used for computer graphics (though they usually have the opposite sign). See for example Sphere Tracing: A Geometric Method for the Antialiased Ray Tracing of Implicit Surfaces, John C. Hart, The Visual Computer 12(10), 1996, pp. 527-545. http://graphics.cs.illinois.edu/papers/zeno

Comment: Like Claude, I too have heard about "signed distance", especially in Riemannian geometry. In this case you have a signed distance from the boundary of $\Omega$. I remember seeing various papers devoted to the study of the regularity properties of such a function.

Comment: Yup, 'signed distance function' seems to be the name. It would be great if you could reference one/some of the papers.

Comment: Do you know about bump functions? They are smooth functions that can be used to indicate sets, but they are $0$ on the exterior, rather than -ve as you ask. They are extremely important in the theory of real manifolds, and are the simplest example of test functions in the theory of distributions.

Comment: [Petersen's book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=YwbNCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA95&ots=cM6zd9CLmb&dq=signed%20distance%20function%20riemannian%20peter%20petersen&hl=it&pg=PA95#v=onepage&q=signed%20distance%20function%20riemannian%20peter%20petersen&f=false) seems to be a quite standard reference.